# django internationalization is not translated to English on the server. Local is normal

Tags: django, internationalization, translate

python: 3.6 / 3.8
django: 3.2.3

django internationalization is not translated to English on the server. But LanguageCode is correct.
Local is normal.

settings.py

```
# 国际化语言种类
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en-us', _('English')),
    ('zh-Hans', _('中文简体')),
)
DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 1
# 国际化翻译文件目录
LOCALE_PATHS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),)
```

views.py

```
def ocr(request):
    translateWords = {}
    translateWords["title"] = _("图片转文字")
    translateWords["clickButtonWord"] = _("一键转文字")
    translateWords["txtareaPlaceholder"] = _("输出内容...")
    translateWords["clickCopy"] = _("点击复制")
    translateWords["numberOfRrecognizedCharacters"] = _("识别输出文字数：")
    translateWords["copied"] = _("已复制")
    translateWords["notes"] = _("注意事项：上传图片最大4兆本应用永久免费使用！")
    translateWords["aboutUs"] = _("联系我们")
    print(get_language())

    return render(request, 'ocr.html', {"translateWords":translateWords,

    })
```

**xxx.html**

```
{% load i18n %}

<h4>OCR {%trans "图片转文字" %}</h4>
```

---

I tried compiling the mo file on the server's direct command line, but it didn't work.
Command  is :

```
python manage.py makemessages -l en_us
python manage.py makemessages -l zh_Hans
python manage.py compilemessages
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0517z.png)

Comment: Do you have "USE_I18N = True" on settings.py?

Comment: Yes, added "USE_I18N=True". I printed the log, and LanguageCode is correct